# How to generate sequence number in asp.net core using ef core 6

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I want to generate "BAN001", this number using EF core in asp.net core and store it in the database, and on every new client is added it should be incremented to be "BAN002" and so on.

Can I do it in EF core 6?
Please help me

Comment: If every single client is displayed like this, why bother with the format? Just use an `int` and let the database do the auto-incrementing. Then simply format the number when you need to display it anywhere.

Comment: I want to generate client code in this format so

Comment: Please tag your database, as there's no pure EF way to do this.  Also +1 to @DavidG.  Don't bother and just use an integer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you already have an auto-increment ID column, maybe you could set up another computed column based on the value of ID column:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    ...
    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(t => t.Id)
           .HasColumnType("int")
           .ValueGeneratedOnAdd()
           .IsRequired();

    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(t => t.FunctionalId)
           .HasColumnType("char")
           .HasMaxLength(6)
           .IsFixedLength()
           .IsRequired()
           .HasComputedColumnSql("'BAN' + RIGHT('00'+CAST(Id AS VARCHAR(3)),3)");
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do that is already mentioned in the comments section by @DavidG but if you need to save this specific format in the database with each client added, I suggest using `HiLo` sequence to achieve that.

The advantage of `HiLo` algorithm is that you can know the key value before calling `SaveChangesAsync()`.

First, configure the Id to use `HiLo` in your OnModelCreating method like below

```cs
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<Client>().Property(x => x.Id).UseHiLo("Client_Sequence");
    modelBuilder.HasSequence("Client_Sequence").IncrementsBy(1); //10 is default
}
```

And while adding the client, set the `ClientCode` as follows

```cs
//create the client without the code
var client = new Client() { Name = "John Doe" , /*other attributes not including ClientCode*/ };
await context.Clients.AddAsync(client); //AddAsync() will generate Id to use
client.ClientCode = "BAN" + client.Id.ToString("000");
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

For more information about `Hilo` check [this](https://jaliyaudagedara.blogspot.com/2021/02/ef-core-use-hilo-algorithm-to-generate.html)